# autohotkey ControlGet only selected combobox value

Tags: combobox, autohotkey

In windows, the "Save As" window for most applications has a field "Save as type" right below the field for the filename. See screenshot below:

[image]

I'm trying to read the currently selected type, but it's not working. I have:

```
ControlGet, Outputvar, List, Selected, ComboBox3, Save As
```

This brings me the list of all the possible filetypes, not just the selected one. The help page for ControlGet tells me about the options "Selected", "Focused" and others, but apparently they only apply to ListView controls, not to comboboxes.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGet.htm#List

I tried using all options described in the help, but I always get the same result, which is the complete list of options. Is there a way of getting only the selected item, or the index of the selected item, or anything that can give me a hint of what is selected?

Comment: I don't think the filetype chooser should be a combo box. Can you enter your own text there? What application produces the save dialog?

Comment: Also, a screenshot would help... a lot. ;)

Comment: The specific application in this case is Opera, I added a screenshot. You cannot enter your own text in that field. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Choice" is the option you were looking for. I just tested it and it works perfectly fine. :)

```
ControlGet, controlData, Choice,, Combobox2, Save As
MsgBox % controlData
```